# Inserting multiple rows with SQL where a record does not exist

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I want to insert multiple rows of data into a MySQL database, but only when my order_id field is unique. This is the current query I have, which doesn't work. Lets say a record with an order_id of 2 is already in the table:

```
INSERT INTO conversion
       (user_id,url_id,order_id,sale,commission,transaction_date,process_date) 
VALUES (1,1,1,'32',0.3995,'2010-11-15 12:15:18','2010-11-15 12:15:18'),
       (3,6,2,'*not-available*',0.001975,'2010-11-15 12:15:18','2010-11-15 12:15:18') 
WHERE (order_id <> 3);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Tom

Comment: so in your example order_id is 1 for both rows. what do you want to do in such case? what do you want to achieve with order_id <> 1?

Comment: `UNIQUE` among `VALUES` or among the table? If in the case above the table already contains 1, should any of the records make it there?

Comment: Apologies - that's a bad example. Editted.

Comment: Unreason & Quassnoi: Unique among the table & values, although the values should never be non-unique anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using REPLACE.

Example:

```
REPLACE INTO conversion (user_id,url_id,order_id,sale,commission,transaction_date,process_date) VALUES (1,1,3,'32',0.3995,'2010-11-15 12:50:31','2010-11-15 12:50:31'),(1,2,2,'*not-available*',0.001975,'2010-11-15 12:50:31','2010-11-15 12:50:31');
```

url: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Thanks all.

Comment: heh.I almost included that in my answer, but I decided not to because I didn't think it would solve your specific problem. Ah well, I'm glad you solved it. :)

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` doesn't support the `WHERE` clause because if you're inserting it implies that the record doesn't currently exist, so therefore there would be nothing for the `WHERE` clause to look at.

The way to do it in the example you've given is simply not to call the `INSERT` statement if the `order_id` field in your insert doesn't match the criteria you want.

If you're calling `INSERT` multiple times, you'd have some sort of code (either SQL or an external program) which loops through the rows you're inserting; this would be where you'd filter it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am in a similar situation, I would create a stored procedure to handle the logic of figuring out whether an order_id already exists.

```
--Run this first
--It will create a stored procedure call InsertConversion
--Begin of stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertConversion 
    @user_id int,
    @url_id int,
    @order_id int,
    @sale varchar(5),
    @commission money,
    @transaction_date datetime,
    @process_date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if not exists(select order_id from conversion where order_id = @order_id)
    begin
        INSERT INTO conversion(user_id, url_id, order_id, sale, commission, transaction_date, process_date)
        VALUES(@user_id, @url_id, @order_id, @sale, @commission, @transaction_date, @process_date)
    end
END
GO
--End of stored procedure
```

Once the store procedure created, you can execute it and pass in the same values as you would pass into an INSERT/VALUES statement:

```
exec InsertConversion 1,1,1,'32',0.3995,'2010-11-15 12:15:18','2010-11-15 12:15:18'
exec InsertConversion 3,6,2,'*not-available*',0.001975,'2010-11-15 12:15:18','2010-11-15 12:15:18'
```

If you want to be fancy, you can include a couple of 'print' statement in the store procedure to tell you whether it inserts the record.

Comment: Fantastic answer. This definitely seems a lot more clean than my solution. Do you have any idea about the difference in performance?

Comment: From my little knowledge of DB performance, I don't see a noticeable difference in performance. Either solution would need to look for an existence of order_id and insert when it doesn't find one. I could be wrong here so don't take my words on this.